# R Return N characters from String based on If function for same string in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I've built a data frame in R which contains a load of ICD-10 Diagnosis categories.  They all consist of one letter then three numbers. What I'd like to do is create a new column based on these conditions:
If the letter in string-position #1 = C or D, return the letter AND the first digit (string-position 2),  else return only the first letter.

So i'd want my output to look like this:

```
ICD10 <- c("A123","B123","C123","D123", "E123")
return <- c("A","B","C1","D1","E")
df <- data.frame(ICD10, shortcd)
```

I've used the `substr` function with a `start = 1, stop = 2` to trim all observations to 2 characters but I can't figure out how to make it conditional. i also tried dabbling with `grep` but couldn't get this doing anything! Any ideas / steers greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe: `shortcd <- sub("^(A|B|C.|D.|E).*", "\\1", ICD10)`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `substr`

```
substr(ICD10, start = 1, stop = ifelse(grepl('^C|D', ICD10), 2, 1))
#[1] "A"  "B"  "C1" "D1" "E"
```

---

Or with `regex`

```
sub("^((C|D)\\d)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\d+", "", ICD10, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "A"  "B"  "C1" "D1" "E"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_extract` in the following way -

```
df$res <- stringr::str_extract(df$ICD10, '[CD]\\d|[A-Z]')
df$res
#[1] "A"  "B"  "C1" "D1" "E"
```